# Count maximum continuous months across multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to count the maximum number of continuous months in a table across multiple rows of start dates end dates.  The date ranges do not need to be completely continuous, only the months need to be continuous.  For example, if a customer has a date range of 01/01/2012 - 06/01/2012, and 07/01/2012 - 08/31/2012, then we count June and July, resulting in 8 continuous months.

Sample data is below.

**Base Table**

`CustomerID     StartDate      EndDate
----------     ----------     ----------
1001           01/01/2012     06/30/2012
1001           07/01/2012     08/31/2012
1001           01/01/2013     07/31/2013
1002           01/01/2012     06/01/2012
1002           07/01/2012     08/31/2012
1003           01/01/2012     05/31/2012
1003           07/01/2012     08/31/2012
1004           01/01/2012     02/28/2012
1004           03/01/2012     07/31/2012
1004           08/01/2012     08/31/2012`

**Results**

`CustomerID     MaxContinuous
----------     -------------
1001           8
1002           8
1003           5
1004           8`

It should be possible to create a sub-table with every single month involved with a loop, and then loop through that table looking for continuous months, however that involves two loops, which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: Can a customer have overlapping date ranges? I expect not, but it could matter to the logic. Any particular version of SQL Server?

Comment: The customer can't have overlapping dates.  No specific version requirements.

Comment: One of your example dates has 2013 as the starting year but 2012 as the end. Is this correct?

Comment: That was incorrect.  I've submitted an edit.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235418/aggregate-adjacent-only-records-with-t-sql as a start. The problem is much the same, but requires adjacent days instead of months.

Comment: Took the liberty of making an SQLFiddle which I submitted as an edit to the question http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eee59/1

Comment: Is it naive to assume that dates are in fact stored using a proper DATE data type?

Comment: The dates are stored using a proper date data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a custom can't have overlapping dates then this problem is easy.  First for every record look at how many months we have:

```
 SELECT CustomerID, ABS(DATEDIFF('MONTH',StartDate,EndDate)) as Months 
 FROM BaseData
```

Then get the max

```
 SELECT CustomeID, MAX(Months) AS MaxContig
 FROM (
   SELECT CustomerID, ABS(DATEDIFF('MONTH',StartDate,EndDate)) as Months 
   FROM BaseData
 ) sub
```

Due to popular demand here is how to do it with a recursive CTE -- note, this code builds on the code above so understand that before you dive in.  You also have to know how recursive CTEs work.

```
WITH rangeList AS
 (
   SELECT CustomerID,
          StartDate, 
          EndDate,
          DATEDIFF(month,StartDate,EndDate)+1 as Months 
   FROM Customers

   UNION ALL

   SELECT R.CustomerID, 
          R.StartDate,
          BD.EndDate,
          DATEDIFF(month,R.StartDate,BD.EndDate)+1 as Months 
   FROM rangeList R
   JOIN Customers BD 
     ON R.CustomerID = BD.CustomerID AND
        Month(DATEADD(month,1,R.EndDate)) = Month(BD.StartDate) AND
        Year(DATEADD(month,1,R.EndDate)) = Year(BD.StartDate)
 )
 SELECT CustomerID, Max(Months) as MaxContig
 FROM rangeList
 GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eee59/14

Some notes about this solution

- startdate must be before enddate (It could be changed to fix this)
- dates must not overlap (It could be changed to fix this)
- you probably need to play around with the join since this depends on your specifications... as was pointed out, this won't work if the start and end date are in the same month -- but maybe they should?  Remember to be careful however, it is easy to have stackoverflow with infinite recursion.

Comment: This doesn't cater for the "continuous months" part of the problem

Comment: "For example, if a customer has a date range of 01/01/2012 - 06/01/2012, and 07/01/2012 - 08/31/2012, then we count June and July, resulting in 8 continuous months."

Comment: Yep. Recursive CTE should be part of the answer. Watch out for the case is which the days don't over lap, but the month do--I'm unclear if that is possible. Ex. 01/01/2012 - 06/01/2012, and 06/21/2012 - 08/31/2012.

Comment: @gvee - there you go.

Comment: First check showed didn't compile in 2012. Invalid param in DATEDIFF, Ambigous CustomerID in SELECT, Missing GROUP BY CustomerID.

Comment: @KarlKieninger - Fiddle up, see link

Comment: +1 Good solution! I think it might be better to use something along the lines of `DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, start_date) + 1, 0) = DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, end_date), 0)` instead of comparing month values as this will fall over when checking Dec-Jan.